# Gradle build won't process Hindi unicode characters

Tags: java, gradle, unicode, hindi

I have added some Hindi characters in Unicode to a Java program.  Eclipse has no trouble with it, and can run this code, but Gradle keeps crashing - apparently this is due to javac making assumptions about character sets.

I believe I could handle this by converting my whole source directory to Unicode, and specifying encoding as "unicode" in the `build.gradle` file.

a) is there an official converter, and b) if so, how can I drive it from the `build.gradle` file?

The program in question is at https://github.com/jpaulm/drawfbp/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jpaulmorrison/graphics/MyFontChooser.java - line 272.  Strangely, Gradle has no trouble with the Chinese characters at line 286, so why does only Hindi have problems?   Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It appears that I should be able to use Eclipse compiler, rather than javac.  There is a Gradle plugin called "ecj", but I don't see how to bring it in - Gradle build keeps saying "plugin not found"...  Help, please!

Comment: I had to back out the added Russian and Hindi text, so these lines aren't currently available on the specified web page.  However, I think switching build.gradle to use ecj might solve the problem, so this is what I now need to know...  TIA

Answer (score 0):

This is embarrassing! I had one segment in Russian and another in Hindi (Devanagari), the former in ASCII, the latter in Unicode. I assumed my problem was with the Hindi, but it was actually with the Russian! When I converted the Russian to Unicode, everything worked fine (both Eclipse and Gradle)! Abject apologies!  I guess we can close this one!